# Grounding polycarbonate or Plexiglas

Tags: grounding, dielectric

If a record turntable's base is made from a 2" think piece of acrylic (for instance polycarbonate or Plexiglas) can it be successfully grounded to eliminate any static charge that it would build up in normal use?

Comment: Is the base transparent? And does it need to remain so? If not then you could use conductive paint.

Comment: Actually seems like you can get transparent conductive paint specifically for dealing with static charge - https://hollandshielding.com/Conductive-transparent-paint

Comment: Some are, some aren't.  I see more & more people purchasing turntables made by companies who are using "exotic" materials both for the plinth (base) and for the platter itself.  Some really simplistic designs and some very wild designs.  But a number of owners complain of a "hum" (in the speakers) which is usually associated with a bad ground in the turntable.

I was thinking that if the plinth (base) is some sort of plastic (a dielectric-right) with a metal motor suspended/attached underneath driving a plastic platter upon which is a vinyl record, that's just asking for grounding problems.

Comment: I belong to a turntable enthusiast FaceBook page and have recently noticed that a number of turntable users have posted that they are noticing an audible "hum" in their speakers when playing their turntables.  To a fault (pardon the expression) they have turntables with acrylic bases and acrylic platters.  It is my general understanding that any sort of "hum" produced in the system is due to grounding problems and was wondering, since the whole unit is basically plastic, just how do you effectively "ground" such a unit? There's really no metal (other than the motor and some electronics).